# IBM Watson Speech to Text: Session timed out despite inactivity_timeout parameter (for a 15+sec file)

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, speech-to-text

I use the code from https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/speech-to-text?code=python#recognize-audio-websockets to send recorded speech as a .wav file to the speech_to_text IBM Watson service and get text back. I get
`Error received: Session timed out.` for files which are longer than 15 seconds, even if I set  the inactivity_timeout parameter to -1. For shorter files it works though.
I also read https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/speech-to-text?topic=speech-to-text-input&locale=en but my problem is not described there.

```
import json
from os.path import join, dirname
from ibm_watson import SpeechToTextV1
from ibm_watson.websocket import RecognizeCallback, AudioSource
import os

##########
# IBM CLOUD: Use the following code only to
# authenticate to IBM Cloud.
##########
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator
authenticator = IAMAuthenticator(os.environ.get("IBM_API_KEY"))
speech_to_text = SpeechToTextV1(
    authenticator=authenticator
)
speech_to_text.set_service_url('https://api.eu-de.speech-to-text.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/2d58dac4-197c-4d7b-9a7e-215d80339ab0')


class MyRecognizeCallback(RecognizeCallback):
    def __init__(self):
        RecognizeCallback.__init__(self)

    def on_data(self, data):
        print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))

    def on_error(self, error):
        print('Error received: {}'.format(error))

    def on_inactivity_timeout(self, error):
        print('Inactivity timeout: {}'.format(error))

myRecognizeCallback = MyRecognizeCallback()

with open(join(dirname(__file__), './.', 'output1.wav'),
              'rb') as audio_file:
    audio_source = AudioSource(audio_file)
    speech_to_text.recognize_using_websocket(
        audio=audio_source,
        content_type='audio/wav',
        recognize_callback=myRecognizeCallback,
        model='en-US_Multimedia',
        low_latency=True,
        inactivity_timeout=-1

       )
```

Comment: From the link you shared - "You can pass a maximum of 100 MB and a minimum of 100 bytes of audio per recognition request."

Comment: my audio file with 24 seconds is 4.305 KB, that is not the problem.